# Word Macro: Read number as a word rather than separate characters

Tags: vba

I a teacher and am creating a macro to look for common errors in my students' papers.  For example, I build a macro to look for the word "profit".  If it is found, it then looks at the previous word. If that previous word is not "operating" or "gross" or "net", then I return a comment to the student.

I have several items like this.  However, when I read through the document and look at the word before or after the desired word, numbers mess me up.  For example, I want to see if students use "and" when using "between" (they often mistakenly use between/to or between/through).  Thus, I have a macro to find the word "between" and then look at the next 2 words to see if either of them are "and".  If not, it returns a comment.

My issue is that if there is something like:  Between $52 million and $64 million... then looking 2 words ahead won't find the "and" because the $52 isn't read as one word.  Should I use something other than words to do this?  Or is there a way to read in a number as a word (or text)?

Here is my code:

```
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
For k = 1 To doc.Words.Count - 3
  j = 0
    If Trim(doc.Words(k)) = "between" Then
    j = 1
    End If

    If Trim(doc.Words(k + 2)) = "and" Or Trim(doc.Words(k + 3)) = "and" Then
    j = 0
    End If

  If j = 1 Then
  ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range:=Selection.Document.Words(k), Text:="the word 'between' should be followed by 'and' such as: between $4 million and $6 million'."
  End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If the definition of `word` in VBA does not suite your purpose, you will need
to do it yourself.

You could read and process the whole document text.
You may get rid of troublesome characters by simply deleting them.
You will then use the
[Split function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)
to split the document.

As the problem is that the Split function allows only one character to use as
delimiter, you are faced with replacing all punctuation and special characters
with blanks.

Another problem is that the Split function treats two delimiters in a row, or a delimiter at the beginning or end of the string, as surrounding an empty string ("").
So will need to replace all repetition of blanks with one blank.

Alternatively, you may use regular expressions to isolate the words.
See for example the Stack Overflow post
[Returning a regex match in VBA (excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146485/returning-a-regex-match-in-vba-excel).